# Installing Ubuntu Maverick on Lenny Xen dom0

Tags: ubuntu, debian, xen

Does anyone have a good way of installing Ubuntu Maverick (10.10) on a Debian Lenny Xen dom0? The scripts provided by debootstrap support only very old Ubuntu's (can't check which ones right now), but even those are just symlinks to each other. So, I thought I could create another symlink and hook directory, but it doesn't work.

Installing goes fine, but booting results in some udev error and a message that I should press ctrl-D for a maintainance console.

When the system boots with the kernel from the dom0, I intend to install grub and use pygrub from then on, so that's how I will get around Debian's old kernels.

I can support more details later (I can't right now), but I'm open to any hints.

Does the deboostrap package from newer releases perhaps contain newer scripts for newer Ubuntu releases?

edit: Debian testing seems to have all the versions I need; Would using debian testing for merely a dom0 be unwise? I mean, I won't be installing anything else, so how much is the chance of breakages?

Answer (score 1):

The version of [debootstrap](http://packages.debian.org/sid/debootstrap) in Debian Sid appears to have support for Ubuntu Maverick. (Or at least, it installs a script named `maverick` into `/usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/`.)

Comment: Backports does as well. I'll fiddle with that. But I kind of fear that the kernel in Debian is too old to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm, xen-tools also needs a hook directory for maverick in /usr/lib/xen-tools. The version in testing has it... Might need to use testing instead.